# get a custom attribute of custom textview from XML

Tags: java, android, textview

**How to get custom fontname Attributes of Custom TextView for Set font to Textview.**
**Based on Attributes value set Font in TextView**

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView
{
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
          // set font_name based on attribute value of textview in xml file
          String font_name = "";
        if (!isInEditMode())
        {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/"+font_name);
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

**In Xml File**

```
<com.Example.MyTextView 
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontname="font.ttf"
            android:text="Header"   
/>
```

**I also Put font.ttf file in assets->fonts**
**Thank You**

Answer (score 6):

1 . Add readAttr(context,attrs) method to your constructor like below.

```
public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    readAttr(context,attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    readAttr(context,attrs)
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    init();
}
```

2 . Define readAttr() method in the same class.

```
private void readAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);

    // Read the title and set it if any
    String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontname) ;
    if (fontName != null) {
        // We have a attribute value and set it to proper value as you want
    }

    a.recycle();
}
```

3 . Modify attrs.xml file (res/values/attrs.xml) and add the below to the file

```
<declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
  <attr name="fontname" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

4 . In Xml file.

```
<com.Example.MyTextView 
   android:id="@+id/header"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   custom:fontname="font.ttf"
   android:text="Header" />
```

5 . Add this line to the top container of xml file.

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourpackage.name"
```

Thats all

Answer (score 4):

First you jave to define a `declarable-styleable` which should look like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
    <attr name="fontname" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In your layout you can "access" this **attr**, but first you have to define a `namespace`:

```
xmlns:myPrefix="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

**Note:** The `namespace` is arbitrary. So you can name it `xmlns:whatever` as well.

And then you can **set** the **fontname** like this:

```
<com.Example.MyTextView 
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    myPrefix:fontname="font.ttf"
    android:text="Header"   
/>
```

In order to retrieve the value you have to do the following in the constructors of `MyTextView`:

```
TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
String font = values.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontname);

// set the typeface etc.
```

**Note:** `MyTextView_fontname`this is always a combination separated with an underscore. So the basic structure is *StyleableName*_*AttrName*

Comment: res-auto is important instead of package name when we are using build variants and product flavors, otherwise we will get an error and never compiled. Thanks @reVerse for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

first add your custom font to assets->fonts directory
[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHcYb.png)

then add this code to attrs.xml file value folder

```
 <declare-styleable name="TextViewCustomFont">
    <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="custom_font" format="enum">
        <enum name="roboto_Regular" value="0"/>
        <enum name="roboto_bold" value="1"/>
        <enum name="roboto_medium" value="2"/>

    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

now add this custom class extending TextView. one thing is that the default is robot regular and it has default value 0. so when the custom:custom_font attribute is not set than a.getInteger(R.styleable.TextViewCustomFont_custom_font, 0) is returning 0.

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {


    public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);


    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context,attrs);

    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context,attrs);



    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        int fontFlag;
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.TextViewCustomFont,
                0, 0);

        try {

            fontFlag = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TextViewCustomFont_custom_font, 0);
            Log.v("fontFlag", fontFlag + "");
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        Typeface tf = null;

        if (fontFlag == 0)
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        else if (fontFlag == 1)
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        else if (fontFlag == 2)
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");


        setTypeface(tf);

    }
}
```

now use this class in your layout file

```
 <com.example.tomal.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"

                    android:text="@string/title"
                    your_choice:custom_font="roboto_medium"


                    />
```

add to line to to parent layout

```
xmlns:your_choice="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```